# Instead of adding new items in Array List it is overwriting the existing items in my app

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that keeps getting overwritten instead of adding new values to the list. I'm not recreating the list each time its only getting made once. If I add the details in manually that data doesn't get overwritten but when I try to add per the method populate data it doesn't stay.  so I'm not sure as to what the issue is.  Here is my full Main Activity class where everything goes down.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView listView;
Button button;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";
String date_out,date_in;
String part_number,serial_number;
int employee_number;
Context context;
ArrayList<Toolinfo> toolinfos = new ArrayList<>();
String currentDateandTime;
Toolinfo tool1;
public static String TAG = "Main";



ToolListAdapter myadapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myadapter = new ToolListAdapter(this,R.layout.logrowlayout,toolinfos );

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    listView =  findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(myadapter);
    loadData();

    //Toolinfo too = new Toolinfo("part number","serial number",333,"date","out");
   // Toolinfo too1 = new Toolinfo("part number","serial number",333,"date","out");
   // toolinfos.add(too);
   // toolinfos.add(too1);
    for (int i = 0; i < toolinfos.size() ; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: tools:" + toolinfos.get(i).getPart_number());


    }

    Intent getData = getIntent();
    if(getData.hasExtra("part number")&& getData.hasExtra("serial number") && getData.hasExtra("employee number")) {
        final String part_number = getData.getStringExtra("part number");
        showToast("has extras");

        String serial_number = getData.getStringExtra("serial number");
         showToast(serial_number);
        int employee_number = getData.getIntExtra("employee number", 0);


        populateData(part_number,serial_number,employee_number,date_out,"out");

     }else {
    showToast("info not present");

}



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addTool();
        }
    });



}

public void populateData(String part_number,String serial_number,int employee_number, String date_out, String date_in) {
    //loadData();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    Toolinfo tool = new Toolinfo(part_number, serial_number, employee_number, currentDateandTime, "out");

    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    for (int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: tools:" + toolinfos.get(i).getPart_number());
        toolinfos.add(tool);
    }
    saveData(tool);
}

private  void saveData(Toolinfo tool) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Shared prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(tool);
    editor.putString("toolobj",json);
    showToast(json);
    editor.commit();

    editor.apply();
    showToast("Data Saved");


    }


private void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Shared prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = preferences.getString("toolobj","");

    if (json.isEmpty()){
        showToast("no data");

    }else {
        Toolinfo tool1 = gson.fromJson(json, Toolinfo.class);
        if (tool1 != null)
            toolinfos.add(tool1);
        else{

            showToast("Object is null ");
        }

    }

}
private void addTool(){

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Toolsignout.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //saveData(tool1);



}
public void showToast(String msg){
    Toast.makeText(this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  //  loadData();
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

here is the arrayadapter class

```
public class ToolListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Toolinfo> {

 private Context mcontext;
int mResource;
ArrayList<Toolinfo> objects;

public ToolListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Toolinfo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mcontext = context;
    mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    String part_number = getItem(position).getPart_number();
    String serial_number = getItem(position).getSerial_number();
    int employee_number = getItem(position).getEmployee_nummber();
    String date_out = getItem(position).getOut_time();
    String date_in = getItem(position).getIn_time();


    Toolinfo toolinfo = new Toolinfo(part_number,serial_number,employee_number,date_out,date_in);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource,parent,false);

    TextView parnum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.patnum);
    TextView sernum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sernum);
    TextView empnum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.empnum);
    TextView timeout = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeout);
    TextView timein = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.timein);

    parnum.setText(part_number);
    sernum.setText(serial_number);
    empnum.setText(String.valueOf(employee_number));
    timeout.setText((date_out));
    timein.setText((date_in));
    return convertView;

}
}
```

Comment: Why not run the App using Debugging Mode? You can set a breakpoint and then follow your ArrayList content row by row while the App is running. However maybe the problem is in your Adapter, but you didn't post its Code, so I'm not sure.

Comment: You've got a lot of debugging toasts and log outputs, can you add some more info to your question about which toasts/outputs you see (and what you expect to see)? You say the issue is when calling `populateData`, so is that method being called? Is `saveData` being called?

Comment: the data gets added to the listview so the adapter is working just fine it just overwrites it.  and the data get saved just fine as well although when loading it its null but i dont think that would effect the listview  since im not leaving the app anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Adapter make the following changes

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

// **added the if else condition**
         View listItem = convertView;
if (listItem == null)
 {
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource,parent,false);


}
String part_number = getItem(position).getPart_number();
String serial_number = getItem(position).getSerial_number();
int employee_number = getItem(position).getEmployee_nummber();
String date_out = getItem(position).getOut_time();
String date_in = getItem(position).getIn_time();


Toolinfo toolinfo = new Toolinfo(part_number,serial_number,employee_number,date_out,date_in);

TextView parnum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.patnum);
TextView sernum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sernum);
TextView empnum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.empnum);
TextView timeout = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeout);
TextView timein = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.timein);

parnum.setText(part_number);
sernum.setText(serial_number);
empnum.setText(String.valueOf(employee_number));
timeout.setText((date_out));
timein.setText((date_in));
return convertView;

}
```

I just put your Inflater inside the if Statement

```
    View listItem = convertView;
if (listItem == null)
 {
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
 convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource,parent,false);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your code is not easy to read, I found that in `populateData()` you do something inexplicable:

```
Toolinfo tool = new Toolinfo(part_number, serial_number, employee_number, currentDateandTime, "out");

myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


for (int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: tools:" + toolinfos.get(i).getPart_number());
    toolinfos.add(tool);
}
```

why do you use a `for` loop to add 1 element? and `myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` should be called after the addition:

```
    Toolinfo tool = new Toolinfo(part_number, serial_number, employee_number, currentDateandTime, "out");
    toolinfos.add(tool);
    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: isn't that the way to add more than one element?  I'm not sure that loop is even correct if ii change the value it just copies it so like 1 is 1 but then 5 there's 5 duplicate entries

Comment: @apklegion your loop executes only 1 time because you start at `i=0` and when i is icremented to 1 it stops because of  `i  < 1`. What do you want exactly?

Comment: i want it to keep new items to the list and not overwriting the previous one.  i thought i had to use a loop to do that

Comment: @apklegion When you use `add()` you don't overwrite

Comment: I'm using the  add() definitely overwriting it  still